# Trying to set the height of my div to 80% of window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is quite simple but I am still new to this.

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
<div class="jumbotron"></div>

   <div class="container" id="main-cont">
         ....STUFF HERE....
   </div>
</div>
```

The image I'm using is 2400px high and I want the height to be 80% of the window height, so I need to set the height of the bg equal to the height of the jumbotron.

Here is my css code, which will show what I am trying to accomplish with the JS.

```
.bg {
  position: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background: url('..//img/top-img.jpg') no-repeat center center;      
  z-index: -1;      
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}

.jumbotron {
  height: 600px;
  color: white;
  background:transparent;
}
```

Here is the JS.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    function setDivHeight() {
        windowHeight = $(window).innerHeight()*0.8;
        $('.jumbotron').css('height', windowHeight);
        $('.bg').css('height', windowHeight);
    };  
    });
</script>
```

The issues I am having are -

1. First of all, I don't think the JS is working.
2. If I was halfway scrolled down and refreshed the page, my css gets out of whack.  The image goes behind the page contents and it looks ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.jumbotron`'s parent is an element with full height, you could use calc:

```
height: calc(100% * 0.8);
```

Or just basic CSS:

```
height: 80%;
```

But [support is a bit touchy](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc). And again, you need to make sure the parent is has 100% height.

---

JavaScript solution:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function resize () {
        var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.jumbotron'), function (a) {
            a.style.height = h * 0.8 + 'px';
        });
    }
    window.onresize = resize;
    resize();
};
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/y9krr4hx/)

---

jQuery solution is a bit more simple:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.jumbotron').css('height', $(window).height() * 0.8);
});
$(function(){ $(window).resize() });
```

## [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blue1086/y9krr4hx/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `vh` unit in CSS to accomplish what you want:

```
.bg,
.jumbotron {
    height: 80vh;
}
```

It is [supported in most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), with the notable exception of Safari on iOS 7. See the link for a possible workaround - when using a CSS preprocessor you can easily automate that

Comment: It's only really supported in modern *major* browsers. I've used it before and had ***huge*** compatibility issues

Comment: I've also used it, and the only major problem I had was with iOS 7. But if that is a problem, and your browser supports media queries, and you use a CSS preprocessor, you can use a ton of rules of this kind: `@media (height: 1000px) { .bg, .jumbotron {height: 800px;}}`. Do this for each height up to 2k or 3k pixels, and it'll work in most browsers. But it sure isn't pretty or efficient.

Comment: and with all those media tags comes a large css file which comes with a large load time